# Way to continue work on other Mac

Tags: macos

I have 2 Macs. I usually work on one, but would like to be able to quickly continue work on the other. That means the following:

- open important apps that are in use (e.g. for develeopment)
- open all iterms and set the correct path
- open Chrome with all the tabs
- copy files changes (in one way only) from main Mac to the other

I do use BTSync for some of above, but still, would be like to be able to continue work in a better way.

Comment: Do you already use git as source control? You could add a bash script that opens your main file in editor.

Comment: Most of this could probably be done with an AppleScript, although it would have to be custom-tailored to your situation. Another possibility (depending on your network speed) would be to remote desktop (also called VNC) into your main Mac from the second one, allowing you to have access to your entire setup from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Although the solutions suggesting GIT or O/S X Server will work one way to keep two Macs in Sync is something like Dropbox. I know a few people who keep their entire home folder there.

Obviously usage of that much disk space in Dropbox will required a paid subscription but for the syncing files issue that should work a treat.

Comment: Yeah, btsync works better for me. However, this is not about synching home folder - my projects are already on github. I want to share working state.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if that's worth the efforts to install and manage such setup for your purpose: What you need is a server (e.g. "OS X Server" app on a dedicated Mac) and enable the "Mobile home folders sync" service. You then need to tell your workstation Macs to sync their local home folders to that server. As long as you don't use both Macs at the same moment, this should work well. Depending on your network, it may take some time for each sync - more or less "quickly".

Comment: I can do the same with btsync, right?